# Simple loop for changing file names doesn't work

Tags: r, loops, vector, user-input

I wrote the following loop to convert user input, which can be single-, two- or three digit numbers, into all three digit numbers; such that an input vector [7, 8, 9, 10, 11] would be converted into an output vector [007, 008, 009, 010, 011]. This is my code:

```
zeroes <- function(id){

    for(i in 1:length(id)){
        if(id[i] <= 9){
            id[i] <- paste("00", id[i], sep = "")
        }
        else if(id[i] >= 10 && id[i] <= 99){
            id[i] <- paste("0", id[i], sep = "")
        }
    }
id
}
```

For an input vector

```
id <- 50:100
```

I get the following output:

```
 [1] "050"   "0051"  "0052"  "0053"  "0054"  "0055"  "0056"  "0057"  "0058"  "0059" 
[11] "0060"  "0061"  "0062"  "0063"  "0064"  "0065"  "0066"  "0067"  "0068"  "0069" 
[21] "0070"  "0071"  "0072"  "0073"  "0074"  "0075"  "0076"  "0077"  "0078"  "0079" 
[31] "0080"  "0081"  "0082"  "0083"  "0084"  "0085"  "0086"  "0087"  "0088"  "0089" 
[41] "090"   "091"   "092"   "093"   "094"   "095"   "096"   "097"   "098"   "099"  
[51] "00100"
```

So, it looks like for id[1] the function works, then there is a bug for the following numbers, but for id[41:50], I get the correct output again. I haven't been able to figure out why this is the case, and what I am doing wrong. Any suggestions are warmly welcomed.

Comment: Just use `sprintf("%03i",id)`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have done that as well, it works. I still want to know why R is bugging with the code above..

Comment: or if for some reason you did not want to use `sprintf` and prefer to `paste` the result together then `paste0(strrep("0", 3-nchar(id)), id)`

Comment: Also note that this does work:  `unlist(zeroes(as.list(id)))` because each component of a list can have a different class so the conversion to character does not affect the other components.  This would also work: `sapply(id, zeroes)` as would `Vectorize(zeroes)(id)` .

Answer (score 6):

Its because when you do the first replacement on `id` in your function, the vector becomes character (because a vector can't store numbers and characters).

So `zeroes(51)` works fine:

```
> zeroes(51)
[1] "051"
```

but if its the second item, it fails:

```
> zeroes(c(50,51))
[1] "050"  "0051"
```

because by the time your loop gets on to the 51, its actually "51" in quotes. And that fails:

```
> zeroes("51")
[1] "0051"
```

because "51" is less than 9:

```
> "51"<9
[1] TRUE
```

because R converts the 9 to a "9" and then does a character comparison, so only the "5" gets compared with the "9" and "5" is before "9" in the collating sequence alphabet.

Other languages might convert the character "51" to numeric and then compare with the numeric 9 and say "51"<9 is False, but R does it this way.

Lesson: don't overwrite your input vectors! (and use `sprintf`).

Comment: You may drop a word on the coercion of 9 to char in `"51"<9` and maybe say because `charToRaw("5")` is indeed less than `CharToRaw("9")`

Comment: It's documented in `?"<"`, "the (decreasing) order of precedence being character, complex, numeric, integer, logical and raw."

Comment: @Spacedman thanks for this interesting answer, which makes total sense. I was unaware of the implicit coercion to a character vector while executing the loop.

Comment: JavaScript seems to do the conversion the other way: "51"<400 is `true` in JS, `FALSE` in R.